# tinyMCE XSS vulnerability and angular-ui-tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, angular-ui-tinymce

I'm using **AngularJS** and angular-ui-tinymce 0.0.9 version.
lately, an XSS CVE (CVE-2023-45818) was discovered in tinyMCE and it was recommended to upgrade it to <5.10.8 >=6.0.0 <6.7.1.

The angular-ui-tinymce version seems to be supporting tinyMCE 4.x version (even the latest).
is there a way to integrate AngularJS 5.x version of tinyMCE?

**OR**, disabling the "undo" and "redo" functionality in the app, which seems to be causing the CVE?

**OR**, another integration tool for AngularJS and tinyMCE?

Thanks.

- I tried Downloading locally the tinymce.js of angular-ui-tinymce and downloading the tinyMCE 5.10.8 version, but they can't work together.
- Tried upgrading the angular-ui-tinymce version to the latest (0.0.19), but it still only supports 4.x tinyMCE version.
- Tried disabling the "undo" and "redo" options from the app, but by the tinyMCE site, it may not be enough (they mention there is no workaround).

*Tried looking for another integration tool for AngularJS, and couldn't find one.